# Certificateless Key Agreement

Tags: certificateless-crypto

I'm studying Certificateless Cryptography and specifically I'm studying a scheme without pairings.

I read a lot of time this paper (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0898122112002490) but I am concerned about some issues in the paper.

[image]

Basically, during the key agreement procedure, when the user $B$ receives the first message, how can is possible for $B$ to know that the public key $R_A$ (along with $ID_A$) sent by the user $A$ is authentic (and belongs to $A$)? Furthermore, how can is possible demonstrate that is calculated starting from the Master Public Key of the Authority?

Ok, the key agreement works but who guarantee me that it is not a MITM attack?

Furthermore, how B retrieves $P_A$ to generate the key $K_{BA}^2$ if $A$ did not send it in the $M_1$?